# Replace website with newly redesigned and developed site without effecting SEO

Tags: seo, web-hosting, wordpress, web-development

We are currently finishing off a development site `dev.example.com` for a business who currently have a website that needs updating `www.example.com`.

We want to display all the content from the dev site on the main site's domain but do not want to affect the main website's SEO score.

Well when we asked the hosting company to point the main site to the dev site they said there would be a negative SEO impact. The whole URL structure will change and Google will notice 30+ page errors. They suggested replacing the files on the live domain and setup the necessary 301 redirects but not sure what they mean by this entirely

Comment: I run a web hosting company.  While your situation may be different, either simply copying all the dev.domain files to the main site document root (the location of web files) or changing the document root is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

> We want to display all the content from the dev site on the main site's domain...

Sounds like a bad idea. If you're working on the dev site and you want to see it on the main site at the same time, then guests will wonder what is happening to the site when they try to browse the same set of URLs more than once. This may also confuse search engines since they will have different sets of content for the same URL. If you go this route then you may be (accidentally) violating Google webmaster guidelines because of your frequently changing content.

> What would be the best way to do this?

Keep the domains separate. Let guests see the currently running main site as-is and when you are happy with the new version of the site (on the dev domain) then copy all files to the new domain folders all at once at the time the fewest number of people will visit your site. It's all the better if the copy is done in one operation. And if the changes are small (such as modifying a few paragraphs on a dozen pages), then the whole upload operation should complete in a matter of seconds. This will limit the downtime and eliminate confusion guests may experience when they visit your site.

If when you're done, you see any issues listed about your website with Google Search Console or the like, then wait a couple days and Google will get the drift.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is it pretty simple to transfer all the files from one site to another?

Comment: If you have FTP access to both sites and a computer with internet, then you just open up an FTP client to each site and transfer the files over

Comment: On a previous website that we created a dev site for we just parked the dev site and made the main site an alias of it. Would that work?

Comment: If by that you mean main site redirects to dev site, then thats not a good idea if you're working on the dev site

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting company gave you good idea about redirection (301).

Example:

Website with old content:

- example.com/page-1.html
- example.com/page-2.html

Website with new pages:

- example.com/new-page-1.html
- example.com/new-page-2.html

Assuming your page-1.html and new-page-1.html have the same content with new structure, same might be the situation for other URLs.

Now, in this situation, you need to make a list of old URLs and redirect (**301 Permanent redirection**) old URLs to its respective new ones. So, in above scenario page-1.html should be redirected to new-page-1.html

There will be no ranking impact if you do this. You may notice minor fluctuation but it should recover very quickly.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. On a previous website that we created a dev site for we just parked the dev site and made the main site an alias of it. Would that work?